# Present UI Alert Controller when loading a URL containing a specific string

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, wkwebview

So I'm writing in swift 2 - a small personal application. I'm wondering if there's a way of testing to see if the URL contains a specific string, and if so, continue loading the page, but also present a dissmissable UI alert

Comment: I'm working in WKWebView not UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

So you have a WKWebView and if the user clicks a link you want to see if that link's URL contains a particular string?

You should be able to set up your view controller as the web view's `navigationDelegate` and then use one the `WKNavigationDelegate` methods like

```
webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
  didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

I haven't used WKWebView, so I'm not completely clear about how you get the URL that the user is linking to. It looks like you'd check the web view's URL property in the `didCommitNavigation` method.

Comment: It's already been setup as the navigation delegate, (i think) - as this is in my first line of code:

"class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {" - 

just no idea how to test if the URL has the string in it, or how to get the URL of the next page

Comment: No, that simply tells the compiler that your view controller conforms to the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol. Next you need to control-drag from your web view onto your view controller and connect the navigation controller link. Then you need to implement the `webView:didCommitNavigation:` method and when it's called, ask the web view for it's URL.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView has property called 'URL' which you can use to get the current url, from that url you can check if that is the specific url or not 
You can check like this:

```
let strUrl = webview.URL?.absoluteString
if strUrl.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("swift") != nil {
    print("Url is found")
//open the UIAlertController
}
```

You can use this method at any time at the url load request time, WKWebview delegate method etc...